# MFC Treeview : How to apply different images to different nodes in Treeview?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to apply different images to different nodes in my MFC Treeview ?
Currently i have have applied one image to my treeview root node now i want to apply different image to subnodes  and how to expand all nodes in treeview , once i expand one node other get collapsed..

Currently i am doing like this :

```
    CImageList *m_pNASImageList;
CBitmap m_objRootImg;

    m_objRootImg.LoadBitmap(IDB_TREEVIEWROOTIMG); 
    m_objNASFolderImg.LoadBitmap(IDB_NASFOLDERIMG);  

    m_RootImageList = new CImageList();
m_RootImageList->Create(16,16,ILC_COLOR8,1,1);  
m_RootImageList->Add(&m_objRootImg,RGB(250,190,79)); 
m_RootImageList->Add(&m_objNASFolderImg,RGB(250,190,79)); 
m_pTreeview->SetImageList(m_RootImageList,TVSIL_NORMAL);

HTREEITEM Htvi = m_pTreeview->InsertItem("NAS1", hparentitem);
                     m_pTreeview->SetItemImage(Htvi,1,1); 
           m_pTreeview->InsertItem("Animation", Htvi);
           m_pTreeview->InsertItem("StoryBoard", Htvi);
```

I have loaded one image for my root and one for "NAS1" , how to load for animation & Storyboard what values i should give i have taken a third image ...

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BOOL SetItemImage(HTREEITEM hItem, int nImage, int nSelectedImage); it within CTreeCtrl class.

UPD:
Import your bitmaps in your resource pain and load them:

CBitmap m_Bitmap1, m_Bitmap2, m_Bitmap3, m_Bitmap4;

```
m_Bitmap1.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);
m_Bitmap2.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP9);
m_Bitmap3.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP10);
m_Bitmap4.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP8);
```

Create your image list for your tree:
CImageList* m_ImageListTree;

```
m_ImageListTree = new CImageList;
m_ImageListTree->Create(IDB_BITMAP1, 16, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255));
m_ImageListTree->Add(&m_Bitmap2, RGB(255, 255, 255));
m_ImageListTree->Add(&m_Bitmap3, RGB(255, 255, 255));
m_ImageListTree->Add(&m_Bitmap4, RGB(255, 255, 255));
```

Set your image list with your tree:

MyTree->SetImageList(m_ImageListTree, 0);

Now you can use ints from 0 to 3 for the 4 loaded images.

Comment: @Sunscreen : can u provide me some sample ?

Comment: An example is posted here:: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox_SysInfo.aspx

Comment: @Sunscreen : how passing int values to Setimage sets the image i am not able 2 understand ? how it is assigning images to it ?

Comment: You should import and load your bitmaps:

Comment: @Sunscreen :I Have imported the images but how to load it using numbers .Pls provide me some sample.

Comment: you updated answers says "You should import and load your bitmaps:"

Comment: Not the comment, the actual answer

Comment: @Sunscreen : Pls see my edited question and help me out.. thanks for your previous help